# jQuery jTable pagination is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, pagination, jquery-jtable

I'm using `jquery jTable` in my web-based project. Its pagination work fine when the number of rows less than 10,000. But when the number of rows **exceeded from 10000**, it causes an unfamiliar issue in its pagination. The pagination start skipping odd page numbering. You can see it in picture below:[image]

My `javaScript` code for `jTable` is:

```
$("#AllProductTable").jtable({
            paging: true,
            pageSize: 10,
            columnSelectable: false,
            actions: {
                listAction: '/ProductDefinition/Select'
            },
            fields: {
                ProductId: { visibility: 'hidden', listClass: 'right-align' },
                ProductCode: { title: 'Product Code' }, 
                // more fields...
            },
            recordsLoaded: function (event, data) {

            }
        });
```

while my `html` tag for `jTable` is:

```
 <div id="AllProductTable" style="width:400%;"></div>
```

I explored a lot\, but didn't find the solution related to it. I'm further unable to understand this miss behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And at last, I got succeeded to solve this issue. I go through the `jquery.jtable.js` whole file and find something strange in one of its `function`. The function was;

```
_refreshGotoPageInput: function() {
    // different logic statements 
    //...

    //Skip some pages is there are too many pages
    var pageStep = 1;
    if (currentPageCount > 10000) {       // if you having  more than 10,000 pages
       pageStep = 100;
    } else if (currentPageCount > 5000) {  // if you having  more than 5000 pages
         pageStep = 10;
    } else if (currentPageCount > 2000) {  // if you having  more than 2000 pages
         pageStep = 5;
    } else if (currentPageCount > 1000) {  // if you having  more than 1000 pages 
         pageStep = 2;
    }

    //....
    // Differnet logic statements
}
```

All you need is just to `comment` this portion of the above given `function`, or modify it according to your own implementation logic.

In my above mentioned case, my **no_of_pages** were increasing from 1000, that's why its taking **2-steps on changing page** and so on.